# JMenu when is clicked create a new Game

Tags: java, jmenu

I have a main class who hold the frame and the JMenu, and another class for the game extending from JPanel. How is possible for when is clicked one option from jMenu create a new game?

At the moment, I have this

```
class Application {

    private static Game game;
    private static TheFrame frame;
    private static JMenuBar menu;

    public Application(){
        frame = new TheFrame();
        menu = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menu.add(file);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menu);
        JMenuItem newGame = new JMenuItem("New Game");
        newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                newGame();
            }
        });
        file.add(newGame);
        JMenuItem scores = new JMenuItem("Show Scores");
        scores.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Score();
            }
        });
        file.add(scores);
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit!");
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        file.add(exit);
    }

    private void newGame(){
//      frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.pink);
        game = new Game();
        frame.addGameToCanvas(game);
        game.runMenu();
    }

    /**
     * Main method
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Application app = new Application();
    }
}
```

But when I click on new Game, the frame get black and doesn't show anything. I had before this on the command line, and all work fine, but when I try to do this using the menu doesn't work. Any suggestions?

EDIT

the code for frame.addGametoCanva(). What it does, is add the game object to a canvas.
    public void addGameToCanvas(Game g){
            canvas = g;
            add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            invalidate();
            validate();
            repaint();
        }

And yes, the game object, have a finite loop, for the user inputs (from console)

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with running a long running task on the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), but without more information can't be sure. What does `game.runMenu` and `frame.addGameToCanvas` do? Does either enter a while loop that does not terminate within a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Added more information to the original post. Game.runMenu() what it does is run the game menu for choose what action want the user do. In comand line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the game object, have a finite loop, for the user inputs (from console)

The Event-Dispatch thread (EDT) is single threaded - it takes care of painting, event handling, etc... If one attempts to perform a long running tasks on this thread, like waiting for user input from a different source (like the console) the EDT can lock up (in other words an unresponsive UI).

Any long running tasks should be placed inside its own [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) or ran via a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). Further, most calls on a *non-EDT thread* should be dispatched to the EDT using [SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html).`invokeLater` or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` (this includes construction of the UI - note the main method operates on a non-EDT thread).

Although, I'm not entirely sure why the mix of UI (eg Console **and** Swing) - you might consider choosing just a single UI.